# Raster package in R does not rasterize a shapefile

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I can't rasterize a shapefile using the raster package in R. I followed the code and tips from a previous post ("Layer wont rasterize using raster package in R, June 30, 2013). However, I still get the same error "trying to get slot "coords" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots". Is this a different issue than the previous post? Thanks a lot!

```
shp<-shapefile(NA_CEC_Eco_Level1.shp")
lcRas <- raster(shp);
r <- lcRas

shp          
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 2140 
extent      : -4334052, 3324076, -3313739, 4267265  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 5
names       : NA_L1CODE,         NA_L1NAME,        NA_L1KEY,   Shape_Leng,   
Shape_Area 
min values  :         0, ARCTIC CORDILLERA,        0  WATER, 1.000517e+04, 1.000668e+07 
max values  :         9,             WATER, 9  GREAT PLAINS, 9.997592e+03, 9.967503e+04 

> r
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 1, 1, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 7658128, 7581004  (x, y)
# extent      : -4334052, 3324076, -3313739, 4267265  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : NA 

zoneRas <- rasterize(shp, r, "NA_L1CODE")
# Found 2140 region(s) and 2334 polygon(s)
# Error in cbind(poly, rbind(poly[-1, ], poly[1, ])) : 
#   trying to get slot "coords" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots

zoneRas <- rasterize(shp, r, shp$NA_L1CODE)
# Found 2140 region(s) and 2334 polygon(s)
# Error in cbind(poly, rbind(poly[-1, ], poly[1, ])) : 
#   trying to get slot "coords" from an object of a basic class ("NULL")    with no slots

coordinates(r)
#         x        y
#    [1,] -504987.6 476762.6

coordinates(shp)
#          [,1]          [,2]
# 0     -322524.6431 -2726795.8939
# 1     1195909.0021   142037.0767   
# 2     2126454.5663  1985314.0739
# 3     2052912.8197  2013519.6523
# [etc, etc]
```

Comment: Did you try fixing the bad coordinate system of the raster r?

Comment: @user3461065 would you mind to share the shapefile? You could share from a dropbox or a google drive file.

Comment: @blindJesse I did not fix any coordinate system in the raster. I am not very familiar with shapefiles and raster files. I just followed how to rasterize a layer from a shapefile from the previous post. I was successful with other files, but not with "NA_CEC_Eco_Level1.shp". I am able to rasterize other layers in this file though, e.g., Shape_Leng

Comment: @PauloCardoso, Hi Paulo, the shapefile can be directly downloaded from: ftp://ftp.epa.gov/wed/ecoregions/cec_na/NA_CEC_Eco_Level1.zip

Comment: @user3461065, install and load the `rgdal` library. then fix the coordinate system of the raster: `proj4string(r)<-proj4string(shp)`. Then report.

Comment: @blindJesse, Thanks a lot for your help! Fixing the coordinate system gives a coordinate ref. to the layer (coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs). However, i still get the same error (Found 2261 region(s) and 2462 polygon(s)
Error in cbind(poly, rbind(poly[-1, ], poly[1, ])) : 
  trying to get slot "coords" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots) when I tried to rasterize the layer.

Comment: The crs was certainly not the issue as the `RasterLayer` was derived from the `Spatial*` object (derived from a shapefile). This probably was probably a bug that has now been resolved.